# .Net Web API 2 Call from a different C# Application

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a .net web api 2, and i want to call the method listed below by an external windows forms application and i couldn't find a way to call it, any ideas?

```
  public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/Put/{id}/{maping}/{data}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(object))]
        [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]

        public IHttpActionResult Put(int custId, [FromBody]Tuple<string,string> mapping, [FromBody]string data)
        {
            try
            {
                // ...... work to do
                var result = new { Success = "success", ErrorMessage = "No Errors", c_CustGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B") };
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { return InternalServerError(ex); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're looking for an HTTP client.

Comment: You'll have to call it using an HTTP PUT request to your Web API server. Take a look at `System.Net.HttpClient`, that will give you something to work with.

Comment: I changed the put method signature to match this call:
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {              
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64878/");
                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Put", "TEST").Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.Write("Success");
                }
                else
                    Console.Write("Error");
            }
and it didnt work
@SLaks

Comment: error message: {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcYmFzZWwuYWJkb1xTb3VyY2VccmVwb3NcVGVycmFub3ZhU3luY0FQSVxUZXJyYW5vdmFTeW5jQVBJXGFwaVxQdXQ=?=
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Thu, 12 Apr 2018 18:29:19 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 180
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}